# Sum over n below x of the sum of reciprocals of primality radii of n

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Under Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote for $n$ a positive integer greater than $1$ by $\mathbb{G}(n)$ the set of positive integers $r$ such that both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime.

Denoting by $S(x):=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{r\in\mathbb{G}(n)}\frac{1}{r}$, is there a non negative real number $\alpha$ such that $S(x)\sim\dfrac{x}{\log^{1-\alpha}x.(\log\log x)^{\alpha}}$? If so, what is the value of $\alpha$?

A few numerical computations seem to suggest one may take $\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

Edit: actually the assumption of Goldbach's conjecture is unnecessary. Were it false, there would be integers $n$ such that $\mathbb{G}(n)$ would be empty, making the inner sum equal $0$ for those $n$. As we know that the number of even integers below $x$ that are not Goldbach numbers is an $o(x)$, that doesn't prevent $S(x)$ from existing and being positive. One may even say that the truth of Goldbach's conjecture would be a consequence of the maximality of this sum among its possible values.

Comment: **Under the random model for the primes** not under Goldbach. In other words generate a random sequence of odd integers with the probability that $n$ is in it is $1/\log n$ and see what you get when replacing the primes by this sequence. If your $\alpha$ seems to be quite stable from a random drawing to another then try to find a proof that it exists and its value, then see what it means for the primes and Goldbach.

Comment: Note that we can write $S(x)=\sum_{p+q\leq 2x}\frac{2}{p-q}$, where the sum is over pairs of primes $p<q$ with $p+q\leq 2x$. From this you see that the problem is more so about prime gaps and less so about Goldbach.

Comment: Wojowu: Goldbach IS a problem about prime gaps.

Comment: More precisely, it's about the number of elements of the "gap spectrum" of $n$, that is the set of positive integers $k$ such that $g_{n-k}=g_{n+k}$.

Answer (score 1):

I used Gauss' method of least squares to get the best fit for different values of $\alpha$. It seems it is attained for $\alpha$ close to $2/3$:

[image]

This would mean that, on average, $R(n):=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{G}(n)}\frac{1}{r}$ is greater than $\dfrac{1}{\log n}$. So if there are few integers $r>0$ such that $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime, $r_{0}(n)$ defined as the smallest such $r$ can't be too large.